# How many possibilities for a numerical PIN with no more than 9 digits?

Tags: computational-mathematics

I understand that there would be 1,000,000,000 possibilities for a PIN of exactly nine digits (10^9, ten being the vocabulary (0-9) and the power of nine being the length of the PIN), but what about for a pin of 9 or less digits?

I am a computer security student.

Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to repeat the computation for length 1, 2, 3, ... and see a pattern pretty immediately, no?

Comment: I'm as confused as @T.Bongers  You explain the reasoning for the answer in your question.

Comment: What does 9 digit mean?  Can a 9 digit number start with a zero?  Any way... if so, you want to add the number of 1 digits plus the number of 2 digits etc.

Answer (score 3):

you want $10+100+1000+\dots + 10^9=1111111110$

Comment: Thanks, it's embarrassment as I understand how easy it is now.

Comment: you are $100\%$ completely welcome my friend.